# connect two sql server and import to CSV file (ETL)

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, etl

I have two servers, both has a sql server . Let's say srv1 has a sql-srv1 and srv2 with a sql-srv2 , i want to get some informations within sql-srv2 but making requests from sql-srv1.

my project is to create a script which could export data within sql-srv2 , in creating a bat files and to execute the script every day with task scheduler but first of all i have to connect the 2 sql-server and i don't know guys how to connect it, i'm a beginner.
I just want to create a script like

> sqlcmd -S . -d demo -E -s";" -w 700 -Q "select * from etudiant" > C:\troisiemetest%date%.csv

which can run everyday on the 2 sql servers linked.
Thank you

Comment: Seems like a perfect use for an SSIS package executed from an SQL Agent job ;)
Maybe you want to have a look at this as it seems to me like a better approch then a batch file that connect  to SQL using SQLCMD

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag if you are only using SQL Server?

Comment: So is this MySQL or SQL Server???  They're 2 completely different products.  Please tag properly.

Comment: @Eric SQL server , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the group....You can also use linked server, below link could help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server

As per the comments, adding the details from the thread mentioned

Querying across 2 different databases is a distributed query. Here is a list of some techniques plus the pros and cons:

Linked servers: Provide access to a wider variety of data sources than SQL Server replication provides

Linked servers: Connect with data sources that replication does not support or which require ad hoc access

Linked servers: Perform better than OPENDATASOURCE or OPENROWSET

OPENDATASOURCE and OPENROWSET functions: Convenient for retrieving data from data sources on an ad hoc basis. OPENROWSET has BULK facilities as well that may/may not require a format file which might be fiddly

OPENQUERY: Doesn't support variables
All are T-SQL solutions. Relatively easy to implement and set up
All are dependent on connection between source and destionation which might affect performance and scalability

Follow these steps to create a Linked Server:
1. Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> New Linked Server
2. Provide Remote Server Name.
3. Select Remote Server Type (SQL Server or Other).
4. Select Security -> Be made using this security context and provide login and password of remote server.

Comment: is it necessary that the ip class of the two servers is the same ? the first server ip is like 170.20.x..x and the second 192.168.x.x . is the connexion possible between them ?